# Stream parse 4GB XML file and write part of file to new XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, large-data

I am trying to stream parse an about 4GB XML file and write parts of it to a new XML file in PHP.

The structure of the ~4GB XML document is like this and **I am trying to keep the `<doc>` elements and its `<title></title>` `<url></url>` and `<abstract></abstract>` children.**

But **when I run this script, all I get is a file with `<doc />` one on each line.** So basically it is copying the `<doc>` elements and making them self-closing, but not copying over its children.

```
<?php

    $interestingNodes = array('title','url','abstract');
    $xmlObject = new XMLReader();
    $xmlObject->open('file.xml');

    $xmlOutput = new XMLWriter();
    $xmlOutput->openURI('destfile.xml');
    $xmlOutput->setIndent(true);
    $xmlOutput->setIndentString("   ");
    $xmlOutput->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    while($xmlObject->read()){
        if($xmlObject->name == 'doc'){
             $xmlOutput->startElement('doc');
             $xmlObject->readInnerXML();
             if(array_search($xmlObject->name, $interestingNodes)){
                 $xmlOutput->startElement($xmlObject->name);
                 $xmlOutput->text($xmlObject->value);
                 $xmlOutput->endElement(); //close the current node
             }
             $xmlOutput->endElement(); //close the doc node
        }
    }

    $xmlObject->close();
    $xmlOutput->endDocument();
    $xmlOutput->flush();

?>
```

Here is what file.xml looks like:

```
<feed>
    <doc>
        <title>Title of first doc is here</title>
        <url>URL is here</url>
        <abstract>Abstract is here...</abstract>
        <links>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
       </link>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <title>Title of second doc is here</title>
        <url>URL is here</url>
        <abstract>Abstract is here...</abstract>
        <links>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
            <sublink>Link is here</sublink>
        </link>
    </doc>
 </feed>
```

And this is what I want destfile.xml to look like:

```
    <doc>
        <title>Title of first doc is here</title>
        <url>URL is here</url>
        <abstract>Abstract is here...</abstract>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <title>Title of second doc is here</title>
        <url>URL is here</url>
        <abstract>Abstract is here...</abstract>
    </doc>
```

But when I run that script, above, all I get is:

```
<doc />
<doc />
<doc />
<doc />
<doc />
<doc />
/* And many, many more <doc />s */
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you're attempting to do:

```
<?php

    $interestingNodes = array('title','url','abstract');
    $xmlObject = new XMLReader();
    $xmlObject->open('file.xml');

    $xmlOutput = new XMLWriter();
    $xmlOutput->openURI('destfile.xml');
    $xmlOutput->setIndent(true);
    $xmlOutput->setIndentString("   ");
    $xmlOutput->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    while($xmlObject->read()){
        if($xmlObject->name == 'doc'){
            if($xmlObject->nodeType==XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) $xmlOutput->endElement();
            else $xmlOutput->startElement('doc');
        }
        if(in_array($xmlObject->name, $interestingNodes)){
            $xmlOutput->startElement($xmlObject->name);
            $xmlOutput->text($xmlObject->readString());
            $xmlOutput->endElement(); //close the current node
        }
    }

    $xmlObject->close();
    $xmlOutput->endDocument();
    $xmlOutput->flush();

?>
```

Comment: `array_search` needs the `!==false` check or you'll never get "title" (position 0)